# Failed to resolve module specifier

Tags: javascript, jshint

I`m only starting my JS journey and I will be really grateful if you help me to receive data using the JS. I found that info on the alcor exchange site that is the exchange site for wax (gaming crypto currency).

What is on site:

// Code not tested yet, and provided for explanation reason

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import { Api, JsonRpc, RpcError } from 'eosjs'

const rpc = new JsonRpc('https://wax.greymass.com', { fetch })
```

// Get buy orderbook from table

```
const { rows } = await rpc.get_table_rows({
  code: 'alcordexmain',
  table: 'buyorder',
  limit: 1000,
  scope: 29, // Market id from /api/markets
  key_type: 'i128', // we are using it for getting order sorted by price.
  index_position: 2
})
```

I faced with some trouble because of JSHint version and updated it to 9. But still "await" is red and JSHint is asking for semicolon after it - which causes huge amount of new errors. However the project is opening in the browser with no info of course. But in the console I see an error.

> index.html:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "node-fetch". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

P.S. I checked the posts with such error but actually didn't understand what should I do because all of them are proposing some changes for JSON file and I only have index.html and that js. file.

Comment: You're trying to use `node-fetch` (a node package) in a client-side script would be my first guess.

Comment: Could you suggest what to do to make it work?

Comment: Create a node server ([perhaps with Express](https://github.com/expressjs/express)), and then [follow the instructions](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs0)

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between JavaScript in your browser and JavaScript on a server.

JavaScript in a browser is the code that can be injected into HTML (inlined or linked), which is evaluated by the browser.

JavaScript on a server is not related to JavaScript in a browser. The language is the same, but the environment is not. It's like “draw in Paint” and “draw on a real life canvas”. Colors are the same, but everything else is not.

So, what you are trying to do here is to run server-side JavaScript in a browser. That's the real reason you're getting this error.

There are two ways to fix this error.

### Probably the one you should go

You should install Node.js, read about npm, init your npm project, put everything into .js file and eval using Node.

In a nutshell, let's say you've already installed Node.js and `node -v` outputs something in your terminal. Then everything you need to do is:

```bash
$ cd path/to/the/directory/you/like
$ npm init -f
$ npm install --save node-fetch eosjs
$ touch index.js
```

Then edit `index.js` using your favorite editor, adding there the code you're trying to run.

You may encounter error due to using `await` on a “top-level”. In this case, put it into an async function:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
import { Api, JsonRpc, RpcError } from 'eosjs'

const rpc = new JsonRpc('https://wax.greymass.com', { fetch })

(async () => {
  const { rows } = await rpc.get_table_rows({
    code: 'alcordexmain',
    table: 'buyorder',
    limit: 1000,
    scope: 29, // Market id from /api/markets
    key_type: 'i128', // we are using it for getting order sorted by price.
    index_position: 2
  });
})();
```

Aaaand, that's it. You do not need to run browser here at all.

### Probably the one you should not go, but can

If you need to run your JavaScript in a browser, then you need to either bundle all the deps using a tool like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) (which still requires you to use Node.js & npm), or you may replace the deps you're trying to use with client-side alternatives.

E.g. instead of requiring `node-fetch` you may use Fetch API.

What to use instead of `eosjs` I do not know, but if you decide to use this dependency in a browser, you will at least need to use [import maps](https://uploadcare.com/blog/import-maps-101/) to tell the browser how to resolve such dependencies. Because, well, the error you've got tells you exactly this: your browser does not know what you're trying to import. Browsers use URLs as import paths, not ids (or “bare names”).